# Kubernetes volume hostPath doesn't work for multiple replica

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to use volumes for deployments with more than one replica at the same time.

I'm using `hostPath` volume type now but the `hostPath` only works on one pod and the others can't to access to volume at the same time.

How to use all replicas to the volume at the same time?

Deployment file:

`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pps-wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: meysam001/wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: aws-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: aws-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /mnt/s3`

Comment: Unless all of the replicas are on the same node, then this is surely [expected behaviour](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)? Why do you specifically need to store files on the nodes' hard disks?

Comment: See persistent volume claims https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/#persistentvolumeclaim

Answer (score 0):

With your issue, I would suggest using the storage solution from the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) foundation.
It is called [PersistentVolumeClaim](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes). This resource exists independently of [Pods](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/pods.html). Data
on this volume still exists during all lifecycle of Pods. It can be compared to
NFS auto-mounted on the boot of Operating System.

You may find these multiple mounting options useful for satisfying all needs of
your Pods ecosystem:

**ReadWriteOnce** - volume in read-write mode by a single node

**ReadOnlyMany** - volume in read-only mode by many nodes

**ReadWriteMany** - read-write mode for all consumers

To create 30Gi volume in ReadWriteMany mode, please deploy yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: helloweb-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

Please note that this feature does work on cloud vendors, not evidently on private
clouds.